# Can't open log.txt file

Tags: silverlight

I want to create log file. 
this is the code that i try to do

```
using( IsolatedStorageFile isoFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication() )
                {
                    using( IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream( @"C:/Log.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isoFile ) )
                    {
                        using( StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter( isoStream ) )
                        {

                                    .
                                    .                                        
                                    .
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But i get an exception in the line

using( IsolatedStorageFileStream isoStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream( @"C:\Log.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, isoFile ) )

The exception :    Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream.

What can i do to solve this problem ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include a full path or drive name in the ISO filename.

Isolated storage files are created using relative filenames as they are stored in a sub-folder not under your control.

Comment: Thanks, this solve the problem. Is there any how to control of the log file location on the disk in this case ?

Comment: The location is dependant on the version of Windows and not under your control. You might be able to tweak it via a registry setting, but generally my advice is *"Don't fight city hall"*